# Trying to copy entire workbook, formulas still link to the old workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to copy sheets from a template workbook into a new workbook using excel VBA:

```
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim shtToCopy As Worksheet

'Opens Template file, and the new workbook.
            Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & "Template.xlsx")
            Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open(MyPath2 & "NewBook.xlsx")

            'Copys the "Approval sheet" Tab from the Template to the new workbook
            Set shtToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets(" Approval sheet")
            shtToCopy.Copy wkbDest.Sheets(1)

            'Copys the "ECL (1)" Tab from the Template to the new workbook
            Set shtToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets("ECL (1)")
            shtToCopy.Copy wkbDest.Sheets(2)
```

The problem is that any formulas copied out of the template workbook will link back to cells in the template file, rather than linking to cells within the new workbook.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy both sheets in a single operatiuon, like this

```
    wkbSource.Worksheets(Array(" Approval sheet", "ECL (1)")).Copy wkbDest.Sheets(2)
```